Transform and reproject ZXY tiles in BNG raster to another Grid type
I am building a React Native app that displays Ordnance Survey (OS) map tiles. The OS tiles use the British National Grid (BNG) system (EPSG:27700) with a different zoom scheme and resolution than the standard web Mercator projection (EPSG:3857) used by React Native Map's slippy map functionality.
I want to display OS tiles in my React Native app. Since I'm handling reprojection in the backend, I need to convert the tile indexes (x, y, and zoom) provided by the OS API to a format compatible with React Native's slippy map tile naming convention. The data fetched is invalid or duplicate, in many cases misaligned. How should I transform and project the required way? If somehow zoom levels and resolution of raster tiles can be scaled and replicated on 3857 format grid.
Current Approach:
Backend:

Convert the OS tile indexes (x, y, and zoom) to latitude and longitude.
Reproject the latitude and longitude from  Web Mercator(EPSG:3857) to BNG (EPSG:27700) using Proj4js.
Convert the reprojected coordinates back to x, y, and zoom using the OS tile scheme formula.

Frontend (React Native):

Use the converted x, y, and zoom values to construct the URL for the reprojected tile.
Fetch and display the tile using the constructed URL.

Finally here's my code:
        async reprojectTile(z: number, x: number, y: number): Promise<any> {
    console.log('Initial X << Y << Z :', x, y, z);
    this.tileToLatLng(x, y, z);
    //transform the x y index to lat long bounds of the tile
    const tileBounds = merc.googleToBBox([x, y, z]);
    console.log('Tile To Lat Lng', tileBounds);

    const northWestLngLat = [tileBounds[0], tileBounds[3]];


    const [easting, northing] = this.transformTo27700(
      northWestLngLat[0],
      northWestLngLat[1],
    );
    console.log('Proj4 Transform 27000', easting, northing);

    // const scaledEasting = this.scale(
    //   easting,
    //   worldWest,
    //   worldEast,
    //   maxLng,
    //   minLng,
    // );
    // const scaledNorthing = this.scale(
    //   northing,
    //   worldSouth,
    //   worldNorth,
    //   minLat,
    //   maxLat,
    // );

    const { x: _x, y: _y } = this.coordsToXY(easting, northing, z);
    console.log('Final Conversions', _x, _y, z);
    
    
    

    const url = `https://api.os.uk/maps/raster/v1/zxy/Leisure_27700/${z}/${_x}/${_y}.png`;
    // api.os.uk
   
    
      const response = await lastValueFrom( this.httpService.get(url, {responseType:'arraybuffer' }),
     
      return response;
  
  }

  transformTo27700(lng, lat) {
    // const scale = (value, min, max, desiredMax) =>
    //   (value - min) * (desiredMax / (max - min));
    // const ea = scale(lng, -20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, maxLng);
    // const no = scale(lat, -20037508.3427892, 20037508.3427892, maxLat);

    const [easting, northing] = proj4('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:27700', [lng, lat]);
    return [easting, northing];
  }

  tileToLatLng(xtile, ytile, zoom) {
    const n = Math.pow(2, zoom);
    const lon_deg = (xtile / n) * 360.0 - 180.0;
    const lat_rad = Math.atan(Math.sinh(Math.PI * (1 - (2 * ytile) / n)));
    const lat_deg = (lat_rad * 180.0) / Math.PI;
    return [lon_deg, lat_deg];
  }

  _getTileMeters(zoom) {
    // return 256 * this._resolutions[ zoom ];
    // return 256 * (896 / Math.pow(2, zoom));
    return 256 * (896 / Math.pow(2, zoom));
  }
  coordsToXY(ea, no, zoom) {
    const tileMeters = this._getTileMeters(zoom);
    const x = Math.floor((ea - _origin[0]) / tileMeters);
    const y = Math.floor((_origin[1] - no) / tileMeters);
    return { x: x, y: y };
  }


Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  Please [Edit] your Question to contain a question.

Any special reason you are not using one of the existing libraries like OpenLayers or Leaflet that would take care of that for you?

We are developing on react native, hence a web view is something we want to avoid. Reasons? Leaflet and OpenLayers don't have native support for react native.
And it is easier to place markers, create paths or custom overlays once the map has loaded on a library that supports react native.
